# What is, here, the relationship between "compound" and "arithmetic return" and "volatility"?

Tags: volatility, returns, log-returns, compounding

I'm trying to find the *exact* (ie, not an approximate) relation between the "Compound Return", "Arithmetic Return", and the "Annualised Volatility" as given the assumptions below, and from there the precise meanings/definitions that should underly these numbers as presented *here*.

[image]

These numbers are from a bank's long-term assumptions. I can't quite figure it out, also not by trying several possibilities. I assume the "arithmetic return" is calculated from the other two. There seem quite a few possibilities (eg, continuously compounded vs annually compounded, ln-transformations, arithmetic or geometric volatility etc.) The source does not provide any mathematically precise definitions.

Can you figure out which definitions are used here?

Answer (score 4):

There is no possibility to convert any two of your mentioned variables into the remaining one. For the compound and arithmetic return you can derive an [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/829212/474480), but that's the best you can do.

The definitions for your statements are:

$$r_{\mathrm{compound}}= \prod_{t=0}^{n}{\left( 1+r_t \right)}$$

$$r_{\mathrm{arithmetic}}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=0}^n{r_t}$$

$$\sigma_{\mathrm{year}} = \sigma_{\mathrm{day}}\cdot \sqrt{252}$$

where $t$ and $n$ denotes the beginning and ending period of time and $\sigma_t$ the volatility measured in time period $t$.

In fact, the arithmetic return is just the mean of a given return series. The compound return gives an indication of how much money would have been made by an investor, who invested one dollar in the corresponding asset/portfolio. The annualized volatility is derived from a volatility (i.e. standard deviation of returns) measured in a shorter period of time. The factor $\sqrt{252}$ is used because one can assume to be 252 daily trading days within one year. For an extended description on this factor you may look [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/41480/29318).